# How to split string into two strings base on delimiter in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dateframe that contains a list of file names, it looks like this below

```
fname
ill_2_uctry.pdf
ell_23_uctry.pdf
fgy_4_uctry.pdf
:
:
:
hilll_234_uctry.pdf
```

I want to split the strings from the fname column into a new name, which should look like this below

```
fname                       name
ill_2_uctry.pdf            ill_2
ell_23_uctry.pdf           ell_23
fgy_4_uctry.pdf            fgy_4
:                            :
:                            :
:                            :
hilll_234_uctry.pdf        hilll_234
```

I tried to use `split('_')` but it will return an output that only contains the first part of the string, which looks like this `ill` instead of the output that I want above. I am wondering am I using the correct method or I should consider using other methods.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `str.extract`:

```py
df["name"] = df["fname"].str.extract(r'^([^_]+_[^_]+)')
```

[Here is demo](https://regex101.com/r/CsvXNR/1) showing that the regex logic is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rsplit](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html#pandas-series-str-rsplit) with `n=1` and `expand=True` to split the last occurrence of `_`

`n`: Limit number of splits in output

`expand`: Expand the split strings into separate columns.

```
df['name'] = df['fname'].str.rsplit('_', 1, expand=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will give you an output that you want

```
d['name'] = d['fname'].apply(lambda x:'_'.join(x.split('_')[:2]))
```

This should work !!

Answer (score 0):

```
df["name"] = df.fname.str.extract("(^[^_]*_[^_]*)")
```

Comment: Try to explain why your code should work instead of just positing a solution